# 2d vector c++ use in Longest Common Substring

Tags: c++

I am working on [codechef practice problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FRK) in which I have to find longest common substring. *( Its practice problem so don't down vote )*

Following wiki and some resources online I got the algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

After understanding I wrote the algorithm in c++ , but its compiling but not running successfully . Throwing error while assigning value to vector matrix  .

```
An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

**1) Whats wrong with my LCSubstring function**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int LCSubString(string str1 , string str2) {

    // create 2d matrix 
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;
    int maxlength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= str1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= str2.length(); j++) {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (str1[i - 1] == str2[j - 1]) {
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                maxlength = max(maxlength, matrix[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxlength;

}   

int main()
{
    int t;
    int count = 0;
    string str;
    int len;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        cin>> str;
        len = LCSubString(str, "chef");
        if (len >= 2) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you define your own function max when the C++ Standard already provides std::max?

Comment: writing c++ code first time , no idea . Can you explain and write in better way @VladfromMoscow

Comment: When first using `vector`'s use the `at` functyion instead of `[]` to access elements.  It makes finding invalid indexes easier.

Comment: Can you point me some example how to use it @NathanOliver

Comment: `matrix[i][j]` -> `matrix.at(i).at(j)`

Comment: Don't confuse me with shortcut /shorthand . Please explain me the basic syntax and how should I use it in general 2d vector matrix

Comment: please only one question per question. 2) is imho too broad anyhow

Comment: I will do next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not properly initialize `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix`. They do not automatically resize when you access them with `[]`, you need to set the proper size beforehand, like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(str.length()+1);
for (int i = 0; i <= str1.length(); ++i)
    matrix[i] = vector<int>(str2.length()+1, 0);
```

Additionally, you are not properly checking for `i == 0` or `j == 0`. If only one of them is zero then the first `if` in your loop won't hit and you subsequently try to read `string[-1]`. I don't know whether it would be correct for your algorithm, but try using logical or (`||`) instead of and (`&&`).

Comment: why not `vector<vector<int>> matrix(str1.size(), vector<int>(str2.size(), 0))` ?

Comment: @SamerTufail Aside from the off-by-one, that would be fine too. I think my version is slightly easier to understand for a newer programmer.

Comment: off by one yes, no where the OP says he says he is new to c++ its mostly about the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: @Sumeet vectors are like cupboards. Until you tell C++ how many shelves you want (and in the case of a matrix, how many spaces there should be on each shelf), it cannot give you a proper cupboard. Trying to put things into a nonexistant (or too small) cupboard will fail. For similar reasons, you cannot read position -1 of a string.

Comment: @SamerTufail He mentions right in the comments of the question that he is "writing c++ code first time".

Comment: Can you explain vector<vector<int>> matrix(str.length()+1);

Comment: @Sumeet what do you think it does? [Feel free to consult documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @Sumeet That line only initializes the *outer* vector (i.e. the shelves), it does not yet say how many spaces there are per shelf. That is done (for each shelf) in the loop. The suggestion by Samer instead initializes each shelf with the proper amount of spaces right away.

Comment: I am edited question now and made proper, thanks for your answer .